# Redux Toolkit Structure with TS

Tags: react.js, redux

I've just taken the leap over to RTK instead of 'vanilla' redux and am blown away by how much less code I need to write. I'm not entirely sure how to structure my slices, however, and figured I'd ask for a small code review so I do not accidentally start breaking conventions from the start. This is how one of my slices is currently looking:

```
import { createAsyncThunk, createSlice, PayloadAction } from '@reduxjs/toolkit';
import bundle from '../../bundler';
import {BundleStartAction, BundleCompleteAction, BundlesState } from './bundleSliceInterface.ts'


export const createBundle = createAsyncThunk(
  'bundle',
  async (data: { cellId: string; input: string }, thunkAPI) => {
    const { cellId, input } = data;

    thunkAPI.dispatch(bundleStart({ cellId }));
    const result = await bundle(input);
    thunkAPI.dispatch(
      bundleComplete({ cellId, bundle: { code: result.code, err: result.err } })
    );
  }
);

const initialState: BundlesState = {};
const bundleSlice = createSlice({
  name: 'bundle',
  initialState,
  reducers: {
    bundleStart: (state, action: PayloadAction<BundleStartAction>) => {
      state[action.payload.cellId] = { loading: true, code: '', err: '' };
    },
    bundleComplete: (state, action: PayloadAction<BundleCompleteAction>) => {
      state[action.payload.cellId] = {
        loading: false,
        code: action.payload.bundle.code,
        err: action.payload.bundle.err,
      };
    },
  },
  extraReducers: {},
});

export const { bundleStart, bundleComplete } = bundleSlice.actions;
export default bundleSlice.reducer;
```

Any feedback or tips on how to structure slices properly is greatly appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

> I am blown away by how much less code I need to write

I'm going to blow your mind even more because you actually do not need to `dispatch` any actions inside `createAsyncThunk`.  It does that for you!

The "pending" action doesn't have a `payload` so getting the `cellId` is a little bit tricky.  You can [see the types of the dispatched actions in the docs](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#promise-lifecycle-actions).  The property that you want is `action.meta.arg.cellId`.

You get better TypeScript support on your reducer by using the [builder callback notation](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createReducer#usage-with-the-builder-callback-notation).  It already knows the types of your thunk actions!

The part that I am unclear on is what your `bundle` function does as it seems like it catches errors on its own?  That's fine but you can also throw errors in the inner function of `createAsyncThunk` and handle them in the reducer with the `createBundle.rejected` action.  You can also use the [`rejectWithValue` helper](https://redux-toolkit.js.org/api/createAsyncThunk#handling-thunk-errors) to customize the error `payload`.

```
export const createBundle = createAsyncThunk(
  "bundle/create",
  async (data: { cellId: string; input: string }) => {
    const { cellId, input } = data;
    const result = await bundle(input);
    // this is the payload
    return {
      cellId,
      bundle: result
    };
  }
);

const initialState: BundlesState = {};
const bundleSlice = createSlice({
  name: "bundle",
  initialState,
  reducers: {},
  extraReducers: (builder) =>
    builder
      .addCase(createBundle.pending, (state, action) => {
        const { cellId } = action.meta.arg;
        state[cellId] = { loading: true, code: "", err: "" };
      })
      .addCase(createBundle.rejected, (state, action) => {
        //??
      })
      .addCase(createBundle.fulfilled, (state, action) => {
        const { bundle, cellId } = action.payload;
        state[cellId] = {
          loading: false,
          code: bundle.code,
          err: bundle.err
        };
      })
});
```